# Would it be useful to convert NTFS to EXT4 with this system setup?

Tags: filesystems, performance, ext4, ntfs

Consider the following system:

- Distribution: Devuan Beowulf.
- DRAM Memory: 16 GB.
- Linux kernel version: 5.10.0.
- Secondary storage: One SDD and one HDD.
- Used as a desktop, including software development which can be taxing on system resources in itself.
- The SSD has a boot partition P1, a large partition P2 mounted as `/`.
- The HDD has a single large partition P3, with different paths in `/` symlinked to place within it (e.g. `/home` or `/home/someuser`, and perhaps some paths under `/var` etc.) It is in heavy use.

How important/beneficial is it for partition P3 to be ext4 rather than NTFS?

Bonus question: Should another filesystem be considered for P3?

Comment: @muru: Actually, I'm not sure - since the answer there was written 6 years ago.

Comment: I don't think NTFS-3G has been re-rewritten to be in-kernel in the past 6 years,

Comment: You should only use NTFS, if you have Windows or at least a Windows repair flash drive. It may need chkdsk & defrag which you can only run from Windows. NTFS does not have Linux ownership & permissions. You should not symlink any system partitions. You use NTFS if using Windows, just for data, but if Linux only use Linux format. I use ext4, but see others being used for data, but not system.